# T-SQL pivot inventory aging by day range

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Writing a T-SQL statement to display items in inventory broken out by day range (pivot).

For example from this inventory table:

| ItemName | DateCreated | PO_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-10-07 | 0 |
| B | 2020-10-07 | 1 |
| A | 2020-10-22 | 2 |
| A | 2020-10-22 | 2 |
| A | 2020-10-22 | 2 |
| B | 2020-10-29 | 3 |

Would like to generate the bellow results (typically a pivot table), showing the number of pieces per `ItemName` per day range. The date used to calculate the # of days since `DateCreated` would be the day the report was ran or passed in as a parameter - in the example shown here, the date used is from '2020-11-07':

| ItemName | 0-10 days | 11-20 days | 21-30 days | >30 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Not sure what would be the best way to write the statement to generate the above results?

Answer (score 2):

I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select itemName,
       sum(case when datediff(day, dateCreated, getdate()) <= 10 then 1 else 0 end) as days_0_10,
       sum(case when datediff(day, dateCreated, getdate()) > 10 and
                     datediff(day, dateCreated, getdate()) <= 20
                then 1 else 0 end) as days_11_20,
       sum(case when datediff(day, dateCreated, getdate()) > 20 and
                     datediff(day, dateCreated, getdate()) <= 30
                then 1 else 0 end) as days_21_30,
       sum(case when datediff(day, dateCreated, getdate()) > 30 then 1 else 0 end) as days_31
from t
group by itemName
```

Comment: Thanks, very minor correction the "and then" should be just "then".

Answer (score 1):

I would use something similar to the following query SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
      SELECT [ItemName],[PO_ID],
CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DateCreated, getdate()) BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN '0-10 days'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DateCreated, getdate()) BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11-20 days'
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DateCreated, getdate()) BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30 days'
    ELSE '>30 days'
END AS PeriodCreated
      FROM [TableName])
    ) src
    pivot
    (
      COUNT(PO_ID)
      FOR PeriodCreated in ([0-10 days], [11-20 days], [>30 days])
    ) piv
```

Comment: Thanks that'll get it displayed. Minor corrections. SUM should be COUNT. get_date() should be GETDATE(). Remove the "days" in "10 days THEN".

Comment: Great, I fixed the query in the answer!